# Can I Use gganimate Right Now?

Tags: r, maps, animated-gif, gganimate

I've been working on a project to animate a map. Below is the entire code:

```
#Adding the libraries; I was under the impression that gganimate would work up to this point
library(ggmap)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
library(gganimate)

#Importing the data using a .csv file; I also geocoded it, but that isn't part of this project
CLCLT_Homes <- file.choose(new = TRUE)
origAddress <- read.csv(CLCLT_Homes, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Creating the base map using ggmap
Minneapolis <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -93.2638397, lat = 44.979969),
                                   zoom = 12, scale = 2,
                                   maptype = "terrain",
                                   color = "color"))

#Adding all the points, including point before and after the first "real" points
Properties <- data.frame(origAddress)
Properties

ghost_points_ini <- tibble(
  Closing.Date = as.numeric(2004/8),
  lon = 0, lat = 0)
ghost_points_fin <- tibble(
  Closing.Date = as.numeric(2019/10),
  lon = 0, lat = 0)

Minneapolis + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = Closing.Date, cumulative = TRUE), data = Properties, size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = 1, frame = Closing.Date, cumulative = TRUE),
             data = ghost_points_ini, alpha = 0) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = 1, frame = Closing.Date, cumulative = TRUE), 
             data = ghost_points_fin, alpha = 0)

#Animating the entire thing
gganimate(Minneapolis)
```

I finally finished this project only to get the following error:

```
Error: It appears that you are trying to use the old API, which has been deprecated.
Please update your code to the new API or install the old version of gganimate
from https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/releases/tag/v0.1.1
```

Before anything else, is gganimate still a useful option for animating maps in R? I realized after I got this error that the source I was using to learn how to animate (I'm not a student, just someone trying to learn on their own) is a couple years old, so I understand if it's out of date.

If gganimate is still useful, how can I use it?  I've followed the link given in the error, but it isn't very helpful in explaining how to correctly install the new gganimate package.  I've tried Googling for help as well, but I can only find vague answers that don't explain much.

If it is not useful, it seems that I would have to start all over since ggplot2 isn't a viable option, right?  Or is there another option which would allow me to use all my previous code and then just add on the new package that would animate it?

I found [this](https://medium.com/@mueller.johannes.j/use-r-and-gganimate-to-make-an-animated-map-of-european-students-and-their-year-abroad-517ad75dca06) more recent source on animating maps, but from the looks of it I would have to change pretty much my entire code if I wanted to use that animation package.  Is this the (unfortunate) best route?

Comment: If you want to install the version mentioned in the error, you can do `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/gganimate", ref="v0.1.1")`. Most packages change over time, some more drastically than others. Its up to you whether or not you want to keep up.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help, since I just get this error at the end of it:

Error: Failed to install 'gganimate' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpk1qK5w/file20101507f0e/gganimate_0.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: That's the only error message you get? There should be something else that indicates exactly what the problem was before that.

Comment: Error : (converted from warning) C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp88P5ox/R.INSTALLee065b6723d/gganimate/man/gganimate_save.Rd:19: unexpected RCODE '[pkg=ggplot2]{ggsave', expecting '{'
ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package 'gganimate'
* removing 'C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/gganimate'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/gganimate'
Error: Failed to install 'gganimate' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpk1qK5w/file20101507f0e/gganimate_0.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: A couple of observations: 
1) You are not updating the `Minneapolis` plot object with the plotting data. So when you call `gganimate(Minneapolis)`, it still has only the original ggmap info.
2) `gganimate` changed their syntax. So I think you need to change (just a little) your code to use the new package. Take a look at <https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate> (specially look the last section). I don't think it will change your code a lot.